# How do I flush a FIFO after reading it?

Tags: c, fork, fifo

I have two executable, `sender` and `receiver`. `receiver` will fork 4 `sender` ( calling `exec('sender')` immediately after `fork()` ) and wait to receive data from each `sender`s.  ( the order of receiving data does not matter. )

`sender`:

```
// executed by four different processes, forked from the `receiver`
fifo_write = fopen(fifo_name, "w"); 
setbuf(fifo_write, NULL); // make it unbuffered
fprintf( fifo_write, "%c %d %d\n", player_index, data1, data2 );

fprintf(stderr, "Sender(%d): send to receiver: %d %d\n", player_index, data1, data2);

fclose( fifo_out );
```

`receiver`:

```
/* fork and exec 4 senders here */

fifo_read = fopen( fifo_name, "r" );
setbuf(fifo_read, NULL); // make it unbuffered
for( i = 0; i < 4; ++i ){
    fscanf( fifo_read, "%c %d %d ", &index, &data1, &data2 );
    fprintf(stderr, "Receive from sender(%c): %d %d\n", index, data1, data2);
}
```

Most of the time, `receiver` receives all four set of data correctly.  But sometimes, `receiver` reads the same set of data more than once.  That is, we can observe the following debug message:

```
Sender(A): send to receiver: 1 2
Receive from sender(A): 1 2
Receive from sender(A): 1 2         # duplicate!
Sender(B): send to receiver: 3 4
Receive from sender(A): 1 2         # duplicate!
Receive from sender(B): 3 4
```

I doubt that buffered IO ( `fprintf`, `fscanf` ) might be the culprit, so I turn all IO into unbuffered.

Another possible culprit might be the timing that `fclose` is called.  I'm not quite sure if this is the real problem, but the [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) page indicates that closing a FIFO before the other end might cause some trouble.

What do you think?

Comment: You are not reading duplicate data unless duplicate data is being written.  I'm inclined to think @el.pescado has it right: where you seemingly read duplicate data you are in fact failing to read any data at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check return value of `fscanf`. `fscanf` can read less tokens than ordered. In that case, you might get previous values.

BTW. You can flush only output streams, not input.

Comment: You can *drain* most input streams though, by reading and discarding data until no more data are available.  That's not going to solve the OP's problem however, which I suspect you have identified correctly.